# StandardController delete() method problem

Tags: custom-object, controller-extension, standardcontroller, delete

Does somebody know what can cause the problem that StandardController delete() method doesn't delete the custom object from the context.
My extension for Standard Controller has such method:

```
public PageReference deleteEntity(){
        System.debug(standardController.getRecord());
        standardController.delete();
        return null;
    }
```

System.debug() shows that an object is in Standard Controller's context. But it doesn't delete. I will be appreciate for any helpful hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because standardController.delete() is a server function. And your method is returning null so the page is no re-loaded hence the server function is not done.

Change your code into:

```
return standardController.delete();
```

And it will work.